# Jtable show and hide column and save the configuration.

Tags: swing, swingx, jxtable

I'm using JXTable which has a setColumnControlVisible(true) which shows a button on the upper right corner above scroll, we can show and hide column by pressing it. I want to remember the changes when the app get close, but cannot figure it out yet, Here what I have tried so far. I check the src of JxTable, but didn't how to get the column index or column number which is hidden.

```
package paractice;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXTable;

public class TableTest extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JXTable table;

    public TableTest() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        table = new JXTable(new model());
        //add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        table.setColumnControlVisible(true);
        setSize(700, 700);


    }

    public class model extends AbstractTableModel{

        String[] columns = {"column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column5"};

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return columns[column];
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0, int arg1) {
            return super.isCellEditable(arg0, arg1);
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object arg0, int row, int col) {
            super.setValueAt(arg0, row, col);
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
            return null;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TableTest test = new TableTest();
        test.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but didn't how to get the column index or column number which is hidden.

Compare the TableModel with the JTableHeader.

Just create a simple loop to check all the columns name of the TableModel to see if the table contains that column. Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++)
{
    Object name = model.getColumnName();

    TableColumn column = table.getColumn( name );

    if (column == null)
        // column is hidden do your processing
}
```

Then the next time you display the table you can get the names of all hidden columns and then use:

```
table.removeColumn( table.getColumn( name ) );
```

Comment: Thank you. such a simple logic.